# React JS render component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my goal is before a route get's rendered I want to check if the user token is valid.

In my App.js I have something like this:

```
       import Home from...

      <Route path="/home" render={
        (props) => 
          <PrivateRoute component={Home}
          {...props} />} /
```

> 

And my ***PrivateRoute.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { read_cookie } from 'sfcookies';
import { Redirect, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.renderComponent = this.renderComponent.bind(this);
        this.redirect = this.redirect.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return this.isTokenValid()
    }

    isTokenValid() {
        fetch(window.API_URL + '/check', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': read_cookie('token')
            }
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonData => {
          if (jsonData.success) {
            this.renderComponent();
          }
    
        }).catch(status => {
          this.redirect();
        });
    }

    redirect() {
        return(<Redirect to="/login" />)
    }

    renderComponent() {
        const Component = this.props.component;
        return(<Component {...this.props}/>)
    }
}

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

**And I get the following error:**

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): PrivateRoute(...): Nothing was returned from render. 
This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I am new to React JS but I assume I am not initiating the component properly? Or?

Comment: So you want to check isTokenValid and render the componenet if true. What you are doing here is rendering a boolean which is not a view so react is complaining. pass a function to the render prop inside App.js and inside that function check if token is valid or not. return <PrivateRoute if true or null if false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import { read_cookie } from 'sfcookies';
import { Redirect, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    isTokenValid() {
        return fetch(window.API_URL + '/check', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': read_cookie('token')
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.isTokenValid().then().catch(err => {
            // withRouter HOC inject route props
            this.props.route.push('/login')
        })
    }

    render() {
        const Component = this.props.component;
        return (<Component {...this.props} />)
    }
}

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: I didn't think people were still using class based components O_0

Comment: Even i have stoped using class component. but its important to learn for someone who has started learning react.

Comment: I think it is a matter of preference, if you have done stuff previously using MVC I think using class components is much cleaner imo, do you guys use functional components instead? @NileshPatel

Comment: I disagree. In fact functional comp are much cleaner. Moreover, there are many benefits of using functional components over class comp..